# How to write a constraint in pyomo to make sure 2 variables cannot be different from zero simultaneously?

Tags: constraints, pyomo

How may I write a constraint in Pyomo to make sure 2 variables cannot be > 0 at the same time ? They cannot be different from 0 simultaneously. One must be equal to 0 or the other or both a the same time.

I get in return trying to set a constraint depicting above requirements as

```
def constraint(model, t)
return model.A[t] * model.B[t] == 0
```

I get a error:

Solver unable to handle quadratic expressions. Constraint at issue

How should his be written ?

Comment: This kind of problems are called _Complementarity conditions_ en `Pyomo` has support through `pyomo.mpec` for specifications you can check [Pyomo's paper](https://www.osti.gov/biblio/1195764)

Answer (score 1):

You can just introduce a couple of binary "helper variables" here to do this, and keep things linear.  Obviously, this will introduce integer values into your problem, so you will need a MIP solver and things may slow a bit (depending on the scope of your problem).

In pseudocode...  and all of the below can be indexed as well:

```
Let:
A ∈ Non-Negative Reals
B ∈ Non-Negative Reals
A_non_zero ∈ Binary
B_non_zero ∈ Binary
M = Some logical upper limit on A, B

Then:
A <= A_non_zero * M
B <= B_non_zero * M
A_non_zero + B_non_zero <= 1
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what I found, but I think the last line shuoud be `A_non_zero + B_non_zero <= 1`